# can I change / override definition of window.getSelection()?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how can I change the definition of a native JS function.

I need to do this in order to test an exploit for a Chrome extension that my team is developing. Specifically, I want the `window.getSelection()` function to return a value of my choice instead of actual selected text in screen.

Comment: `window.getSelection = function ...`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to `'patch'` the `getSelection` function, so

```
var originalGetSelection = window.getSelection;
window.getSelection = function() {
// your own stuff here
const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); // convert arguments as array of
return originalGetSelection.apply(window, args);
}
```